# Any ideas on how to handle a Framework resource extraction failed. error that mysteriously started showing up in UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, msbuild

I started getting the following error in UWP today and have no explanation as to where it came from

> C:\Users\chris.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk\2.2.9\tools\CoreRuntime\Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime.targets(195,9):

**Error**

> Framework resource extraction failed. This .resources file should not be read with this reader. The resource reader type is "System.Resources.Extensions.DeserializingResourceReader, System.Resources.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".

btw: line 195 of Microsoft.Net.CoreRunTime.targets is

```
 <ResourceHandlingTask
          AssemblyList="@(_FullAppLibrariesUnfiltered)"
          OutResWPath="$(ResWOutputFullPath)"
          SkipFrameworkResources="$(SkipMergingFrameworkResources)"
          StateFile="$(ResWOutputFullPath.TrimEnd('\'))\ResourceHandlingTask.state">
```

I've tried checking out a previous version of code in Git when everything built and this little beauty is still there.  Cleaning all projects, updating to the latest Visual Studio, reverting nuget packages, nothing seems to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reduce `microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk` version to 2.2.8?

Comment: I did, I even went as low as 2.1.0 but it didn't make a difference.  After another 8 hours trying everything I could think of (and walking through git history) I found the problem.  The following line was added to a project file that is linked in my Xamarin Forms Solution

<GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>true</GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>

Once I took this out it started working again.  I had to start by going back several weeks to get a version that worked and worked back from there.

Comment: I found you have solved your issue, you could post your comment as answer for this issue and mark yourself to convenient people who visit this thread later.